# Error 1064, my SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am really new to this so don't laugh .
I am trying to input a command in MySQL but I keep getting this syntax error.
It is prolly stupid, but I have little to no knowledge in sql.

```
CREATE TABLE `serial`.`serial`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `hwid` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)
```

It keeps giving me : 
**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
    `hwid` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)' at line 3
```

If someone could help me, it would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: You need to specify the length of the VarChars

Answer (score 0):

`varchar` needs to be declared with a length:

```
CREATE TABLE `serial`.`serial` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `hwid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6152e4) is a little SQL Fiddle showing it.